# ImageView giving glib error

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, glib, ros

When I try to launch image_view a window display shows up and  freezes .

The terminal output is as follows :

```
(image_view:29293): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(image_view:29293): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(image_view:29293): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 release using ROS-Indigo 

A similar error is reported on [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/35784/image_view-giving-glib-errors-and-not-displaying-a-window/) site but with no fix 

Also rqt_image_viewer works as given in the link above but only for uncompressed images and hence i cannot view images sent over by other camera devices for eg android-camera since they are compressed as shown below [image: Problem]

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer; the critical warning on the console is just telling you that you're trying to pass NULL to a function expecting a GtkWidget.

Comment: Can you please tell what other information you need I dont mind telling ?
Also I am using opencv 2.4.10 compiled with qt-5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding OpenCV with Qt4 or Qt off in cmake fixes this problem 
More info in this.
[link](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/696)